# Round corners for existing drawing in powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is it possible to make corners rounded for existing drawings in Microsoft PowerPoint 2016?

### Motivation

I have two relevant scenarios:

1. Preexisting drawings, where the hard corners don't match the aesthetic of the current slides. In this case, redoing the drawings loses to just using the old drawings in terms of cost vs benefit.
2. When creating complex shapes with the boolean "combine shapes" tools, keeping the edges rounded through the process means a lot of extra effort. It would be easier to create the shapes without rounded corners first, and then round the corners after the fact.

   In order to produce single-colored rounded shapes without visible contour lines, a thick contour line with rounded corners can be used as a workaround, but this cannot be used if the contour line needs to be visible, or when gradient filling is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little vba will help:

```
Sub RoundEm()
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
            oSh.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
            ' You'll want to adjust this to a much smaller number
            ' But this is for drama ;-)
            oSh.Adjustments(1) = 0.5
        End If
    Next    ' shape
Next    ' slide

End Sub
```

Comment: Won't help much for me. The drawings I am thinking of are more complex, such as multiple shapes combined with boolean operations (e.g. a cog wheel created by merging a circle with multiple polygons).

Comment: @kdb I understand. You're right, no joy there. "Booleanized" shapes don't have any .Adjustments, so would be immune to this approach.